# Bigquery estimates (and bills) query cost incorrectly in partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery, database-partitioning

I have a table similar to the following

```
CREATE TABLE `main.viewings`
(
  event_time TIMESTAMP,
  other_columns INT64,
    more_columns STRING
)
PARTITION BY DATE(event_time)
OPTIONS(
  partition_expiration_days=365
);
```

I then aggregate every new day's data and append that into a reporting table similar to below

```
DECLARE from_event_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(IFNULL(MAX(`date`), '2022-10-31'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) FROM main.`reporting_table`);
DECLARE to_event_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE());

SELECT DISTINCT DATE(event_time) AS `date`
FROM main.`viewings`
WHERE
    event_time >= from_event_time
    AND event_time < to_event_time;
```

Due to some reason, bigquery incorrectly estimates and bills me for the entire size of the viewings table. If I hard code the values for from_event_time and to_event_time, then it correctly estimates a much smaller value.

What's more perplexing, if I only have `event_time >= from_event_time` in the WHERE condition, then too it estimates it correctly. Only when I add `event_time < to_event_time`, it starts messing up.

Has anyone faced something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While what David mentioned is true, I did some testing and declaring the variable as below makes it work somehow. It doesn't estimate right though, but on execution, it charges me the actual (smaller) query cost.

I was able to discover this adjustment to the query by re-creating the table, in staging, and using `require_partition_filter = TRUE` in the partition options. Initially it said there was no event_time filter, but after adjusting the query, to ensure the query can see it, the same query works in production.

```
DECLARE from_event_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT TIMESTAMP( (SELECT DATE_ADD(IFNULL(MAX(`date`), '2022-10-31'), INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM main.`reporting_table`) );
```

Comment: According to the docs, this setting is not related to how pruning or costs derived by pruning work. This setting only forces the queries to include the partition column, otherwise an error is raised.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#require-filter

Comment: I understand, but my point was that BQ in some instance didn't even detect that I had passed a dynamic WHERE condition. When I adjusted my DECLARE statement and it no longer showed the error, even the pruning happened during query execution time.

In other words, you can mention dynamic WHERE condition and have pruning work.

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behaviour. Bigquery will prune partitions only under certain conditions, otherwise a full scan is required.

For example, using dynamic values for the partition field.

More information: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#use_a_constant_filter_expression

In your case, this query will prune partitions and it is in fact an example in the docs.

DECLARE to_event_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE());

But the first one is dynamic triggering then a full scan.

Be careful about exceptions while querying partitioned tables.